# How to prove that $\frac{1-z}{|1-z|}$ is a root of unity with $z=e^{i\frac{2\pi}{n}}$

Tags: complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, finite-groups

Let $z=e^{i\frac{2\pi}{n}}$ with $n\ge 1$

> Then prove that $$ Z= \frac{1-z}{|1-z|}$$ is also a root of unity and find its order.

Reminder $x$ is said to be the root of the unity of order $n$ if and only if $n$ is the smallest integer such that  $x^n =1$.

As a guess first I tried to compute $Z^n$ (without any reason but since $z^n =1$)  but it turn out  that $Z^n\neq 1.$

How can one find or guess the order of $Z$. Any tips are welcome

Comment: What's the argument of $1-z$. You might like to draw some triangles!

Comment: Even though $Z^n$  isn't $1$, it's a root of unity of very small and easily recognized order.  Understanding that order will give you a lot of information (though not quite complete information) about the order of $Z$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you see $z-1$, it's usually a good choice to set $z=u^2$, in your case
$$
u=\exp\left(\frac{i\pi}{n}\right)=e^{i\alpha}
$$
which has $|u|=1$.

Then $z-1=u^2-1=u^2-u\bar{u}=u(u-\bar{u})=2iu\sin\alpha$. Then
$$
\frac{z-1}{|z-1|}=
\frac{2iu\sin\alpha}{2\lvert\sin\alpha\rvert}=iu
$$
because $\alpha=\pi/n$ and $\sin\alpha>0$. Now it should be easy.

A different approach is to square the number $w=(z-1)/|z-1|$, to get
$$
w^2=\frac{(z-1)^2}{(z-1)(\bar{z}-1)}=\frac{z-1}{z^{-1}-1}=-z
$$
Now it's clear that
$$
w^{2n}=(-1)^nz^n
$$

Comment: then the oder is $4n$ thanks

Comment: Not always, I think.

Comment: @GuyFsone It depends on $n$.

Comment: @egreg yes thanks once more

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Using the triangle with vertices in  $0, 1,z$ we find that :
$$\arg(1-z)=\pi-\left(\frac{\pi-\frac{2\pi}{n}}{2} \right)$$